# Getting images from output stream

Tags: bufferedimage, outputstream, javax.imageio

I've a output stream named 'output'

I've turned it into an input stream using

```
byte[] data = output.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

Now, I understand getting the first picture I simply do:

```
File outputfile = new File("imagetest.jpg");
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
```

but how do I access the rest if possible at all? thanks

Comment: Why are you turning an output stream into an input stream? Also, what do you mean by the rest of the images? JPEGs only hold one image.

Comment: Basically i've a library called pdfbox, i've got a image extractor in a loop writing to incrementing .jpg files like 1.jpg.. 2.jpg as it finds them from the pdf. I want to skip that step in terms of outputting to incrementing jpegs and just use the 'write2outputstream' method instead. I thought this method would mean that the output stream would in some way or another be holding all of the images and i'd be able to access them some how. Am I wrong?

Comment: An easier way would be have multiple output streams, one for each file.

Comment: so I should write each file to one output stream and then retrieve them all back from individiaul file streams? is that ok to do? there's gonna be like 500-600 jpgs a time.. it's surely got to be better than writing to disk then reading the disk though i guess. thank you, i'll try it soon.

Comment: There seems to be some code missing here (you first have an `input` then suddenly an `image`).. But it's always going to be faster (and save a lot of memory in the process) to write the data directly to disk, rather than decoding first, then encoding again. In addition, if the data is JPEG (or other lossy format) you'll lose a little quality for each encode/decode cycle.